# Lexemes not persisted to disk

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Using spacy==2.3.0 I am serving responses through an API and as such need to persist the pipeline and custom tokens so that when the server is brought down and back up the state is unchanged. I am finding that through either ***nlp.to_disk()*** or ***nlp.vocab.to_disk()*** (https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading) the lexemes are not written out and therefore my predictions change when I reload the API server.

example:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
print(len(nlp.vocab))  # 478
nlp.vocab["add"]
print(len(nlp.vocab))  # 479

# save to disk
nlp.to_disk(dir)

# reload from disk
nlp = nlp.from_disk(dir)
print(len(nlp.vocab))  # 478 - 'add' is lost
```

I've attempted the same above by directory using the Vocab().to_disk() and I get the same results. Is there a way to persist all of the custom lexemes to disk to reload at a later state?

Comment: What information in the vocab are you trying to preserve?

Answer (score 1):

This is a change from v2.2 to v2.3 to improve model size and model loading time. The lexeme files mainly contained a lot of easily derivable information (`is_alpha`, `prefix`, `suffix`, etc.) and took a lot of extra time to load.

The non-derivable features `cluster`, `norm`, and `prob` have been moved into separate `lookups` tables so they are saved with the model. The only non-derivable  feature that wasn't preserved is `is_stop`.

In general it's better to think of the vocab as a cache for strings that have been seen before during processing and whether a token is in the vocab isn't a particularly meaningful piece of information. The meaning of `is_oov` changes from "doesn't have a cluster/prob" to "doesn't have a vector".

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in my searching I stumbled on the removal of the lexemes.bin in v2.3 (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/5238).

I was able to get around using the to_disk() methods and not having the entire vocab persisted by leveraging DocBin() and adding each tokens Doc() object. This may not be the best approach but it works.

tokenization process:

```
tokens = []
for tkn in nlp(text):
    tokens.append(tkn)
```

persist process function:

```
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE"], store_user_data=True)
unique_tokens = set(tokens)
for t in unique_tokens:
    doc_bin.add(t.doc)

_directory = f"{directory}"
_bytes = doc_bin.to_bytes()
with open(_directory, "wb") as f:
    f.write(_bytes)
```

load persisted file function:

```
from pathlib import Path
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
_directory = f"{directory}"
doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE"], store_user_data=True)
token_file = Path(_directory)
if not token_file.exists():
    return nlp
else:
    data = Path(_directory).read_bytes()
    doc_bin = doc_bin.from_bytes(data)
    _ = list(doc_bin.get_docs(nlp.vocab))
return nlp
```

Comment: I still don't understand what information you're actually trying to preserve/restore here? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Essentially, I'm finding that as I input text through nlp() and it gets tokenized and saved to the vocabulary our downstream model scores are scored to specific values but based on some logic when I restart the API server our scores change because once re-loaded into memory the custom tokens are no longer in the vocab. Part of my logic is trying to identify keywords/words based off if it exists in the nlp.vocab and once re-loading the model when the API starts up fresh all of the custom tokens from the last API startup are now gone.

Comment: The tokens that have been seen so far are saved as part of the model in the string store, so if you save and reload the model, you should be able to look at `token_text in nlp.vocab.strings` to see if you've seen a particular token before. There are some strings other than tokens that are in the string store (annotation labels like `NOUN` or `nsubj`), but for the most part it's token strings, lemma strings, and potentially other strings added by your custom components.